# Jython not getting the python method. Why?

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm really new to Jython and I have a code like this:

```
    interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('my-path')\nimport hello");
    PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("getDriverObect");
```

`someFunc` is always `null`! Here is the corresponding code for python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def getDriverObect():
    c = webdriver.Safari()
    return c
```

I tried the following the combination as well, nothing is working out:

```
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("hello.getDriverObect");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("hello.getDriverObect()");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("getDriverObect()");
```

Where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function object is not available via `interpreter.get("getDriverObject")` unless you use `from hello import getDriverObject`.

Simplified hello.py:

```
def getDriverObject():
    return "TEST"
```

Java code:

```
interpreter.exec("from hello import getDriverObject");
PyObject func = interpreter.get("getDriverObject");
System.out.println(func);
System.out.println(func.__call__());
```

Output from the above:

```
<function getDriverObject at 0x2>
TEST
```

You could also do it like this:

```
interpreter.exec("import hello");
PyObject module = interpreter.get("hello");
PyObject func = module.__getattr__("getDriverObject");
```